# BlogEngine Syntax Highlighter broken with CoolBlue theme

Tags: blogengine.net, syntaxhighlighter

I have recently installed a fresh copy of BlogEngine 2.7. I have been trying to add a new post with some c# code on it, and I wanted to use the `Syntax Highlighter` extension on my post. This is the code I have:

```
<pre class="brush: c-sharp;">
using System;
</pre>
```

But even adding such a simple c# statement is causing the code in my post to look not well formatted:

[image]

Just imagine how it looks with a lot of code.

I have tried many different things (downloading different versions of the extension, and people's fixes) without any success. 
I am using the CoolBlue theme, which I think is causing this problem.

Have any of you run into this problem? Could you perhaps guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it locally and track the problem down to coolblue.css.

If you still want to fix it, modify the coolblue.css and add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
.syntaxhighlighter code {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will reset code elements that live inside a syntax highlighter into inline elements.